Where is this verse quoted from?
brahmacari grhastho va mrtadaro vanecarah
jnatva samyak param-brahma tyaktva sangan-parivrajet
“After he has come to understand the nature of the Supreme, a student, a householder, or a forest-hermit should become detached and become a wandering mendicant.” (Smrti-sastra)
